# Pull up resistor why is it low when switch is pressed

Tags: arduino, resistors, pullup

When the switch in a pull up resistor is pressed why would the voltage in the pin be read as low? wouldn't closing the switch also connect VCC to the ground? wouldn't that mean that the voltage at the pin just be the voltage coming out of the resistor? since the GPIO pin is connected to the output of the resistor which are both connected to ground.

thank you

Comment: Do you understand the concept of a voltage divider? What happens if the resistance of the lower resistor goes to zero?

Comment: You need a diagram and/or a much better de4scription of the connections involved.  If the resistor goes from pin to V+ and the switch goes from pin to ground then Vpin with switch closed is V+ x Rswitch/(Rswtich + Rpullup). As R switch is always << Rpullup the result is Vpin is essentially at ground.

Comment: `wouldn't closing the switch also connect VCC to the ground?` ... no, it would connect one end of the resistor to ground ... the other end of the resistor would be connected to Vcc

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr5hMm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the left-hand case (switch open) no current flows through R1 (assuming the meter does not draw any current) and the voltage is V1.

In the right-hand case (switch closed), about 1mA flows through R2 and the voltage is 0V.

The switch is not connected to V1 so it cannot "short" it.

GPIO pins, when configured as inputs without pullup or pulldowns, behave very much like the ideal voltmeter, drawing almost no current under normal conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The circuit below is a reasonable representation of a standard microcontroller GPIO. In this representation, the GPIO is 8 bits wide. Only two pins are shown entirely, the others are omitted for clarity.
As you can see, the pins IO2, and IO4 are always connected to the input data register, whether the pin is enabled as an output or not.

The OutputEnable4 switch for IO4 is open do that IO4 is considered as an input. The PullUpEnable4 switch is closed so the Rpullup4 resistor is connected to VCC.

When the switch (SW) is open, there **is no** current in Rpullup4 so all of VCC appears on the IO4 pin.

When the switch (SW) is closed, there **is** current in Rpullup4 so all of VCC is dropped across Rpullup4 because the closed switch is connected to ground. So \$0 V\$ appears on the IO4 pin.

> wouldn't closing the switch also connect VCC to the ground?

Because VCC is connected to one side if Rpullup4, the other side that is connected to the pin is grounded thus pulling the pin low. The pullup resistor isolates VCC from the pin and therefore from the applied ground.

> wouldn't that mean that the voltage at the pin just be the voltage coming out of the resistor?

The voltage doesn't really "come out" of the resistor. Current comes out of the resistor. Think of the switch as a resistor that can be changed from \$\infty \Omega \$ (open) to \$0 \Omega \$ (closed). VCC is always applied to the series combination of Rpullup4 and SW. When SW is open it is so large that all of VCC appears across the switch. When SW is closed it is so small that current flows causing all of VCC to appear across Rpullup4.

The LED connected to a pin configured as an output is not necessary to answer your question but is included to more completely describe the nature of the GPIO.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5l8SP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>